# How to get the quaternionic analytic signal of a image?

Tags: image-processing, signals, filtering, fft

the 2D signal's (f(x,y)) quaternionic fourier transform can be described as F(u,v), and its 2D analytic signal can often be described as:

```
  Fq(u,v) = (1+sgn(u))(1+sgn(v))F(u,v)  (in frequency domain)

      sgn(u) = 1  (if u>0);
  ==> sgn(u) = 0  (if u=0); 
      sgn(u) = -1 (if u<0).
```

in many papers, after the define of this quaternionic analytic signal, the author usually gives a quaternionic gabor filter in image processing to demonstrate the useful of this method.

Q:

1. in frequency domain after fourier transform, when will u<0, and when will u>0.
2. what is the meaning of this quaternionic analytic signal
3. how to implement the above quaternionic gabor filter in a image to get the analytic signal.

Note: maybe my understanding of this concept is weak, and welcome to give a specific detailed demonstration.

Thank you.

Comment: This question needs to be on dsp.stackexchange.com

Comment: @KillaKem Yes, either [dsp](http://dsp.stackexchange.com) or even [physics](http://physics.stackexchange.com) where there are [related questions](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/46948).

Comment: @RogerRowland, this is my first question and I did not quite know about the rule. Anyway, thank you for your suggestion, and I will move this to that site.